# slide dependent subitemize in beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

I'm not sure if I do it well but I have what follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,t]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\frame[t]{
\begin{block}{Title}
     \begin{itemize}
     \item text 1
     \only<1>{%
         \begin{itemize}%
            \item subtext 1
            \item subtext 2
         \end{itemize}}
 \only<2-3>{\item text 2}
 \only<3>{\item text 3}
     \end{itemize}
\end{block}}
\end{document}
```

When the items move vertically when moving forward in the presentation: is there a way to fix this? (I've tried `\onslide` instead but it freezes vertical space which I do not want).

**Added:** (by Andrew Stacey) To clarify the problem: it is that in the above document, the `text 1` (which is shown on all slides) shifts vertically ever-so-slightly-but-noticeably between frames 1 and 2.  As it is the first item in the list and there is plenty of space on the slide, this doesn't not seem the right behaviour.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but note that you can write `\item<2-3> .. ` instead of `\only<2-3>{\item .. }`.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks. Don't you think that the mentioned behaviour could be reported as a beamer bug?

Comment: It's not clear what the desired output should be. `\only` has the items move about, and `\onslide` has the items stay put. What do you _want_ to happen when you move to slide two?

Comment: Ah. So the problem is that the `Item 1` moves slightly when moving to slide 2. Is that the issue?

Comment: yes, this is correct.

Comment: I edited the clarification (from the comments) in to the question as I think this is a very subtle error which people might not see at first, so might not realise what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *conjecture* that this is to do with when TeX knows that the paragraph containing the `text 1` has been finished.  The inner itemize starts a new paragraph and so **shouldn't** affect the spacing about the previous `\item`, but it does.  Exactly what shape or form this confusion takes, I don't know.  One could well envision this as a bug.

However, despite not knowing exactly what is going on, I can suggest a simple fix: ensure that the paragraphs are clearly separated.  Viz, put a blank line after the jumping `\item`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,t]{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22809/86}
\begin{document}
\frame[t]{
\begin{block}{Title}
     \begin{itemize}
     \item text 1

     \only<1>{%
         \begin{itemize}%
            \item subtext 1
            \item subtext 2
         \end{itemize}}
 \only<2-3>{\item text 2}
 \only<3>{\item text 3}
     \end{itemize}
\end{block}}
\end{document}
```

For consistency, but for nothing else, you could have a blank line after the sub-itemized list.

Interestingly, I only got this behaviour with `itemize` and `enumerate` and not with any other environments that I tried (including `description`).  Moreover, it is nothing to do with the `\only` since the following code shows the issue:

```
\documentclass[10pt,fleqn,t]{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22809/86}
\begin{document}
\frame[t]{
\begin{block}{Title}
     \begin{itemize}
     \item text 1
         \begin{itemize}%
            \item subtext 1
            \item subtext 2
         \end{itemize}
     \end{itemize}
\end{block}}

\frame[t]{
\begin{block}{Title}
     \begin{itemize}
     \item text 1
  \item text 2
     \end{itemize}
\end{block}}
\end{document}
```

and the same blank line fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the output using 
`\item<2-3> text 2`
then you can try use an empty "space kipper", that is:

```
\only<1,4->{\item \mbox{}}
\only<2-3>{\item text 2}
```

Comment: This adds a blank item on the first slide (and on a new fourth slide). What you presumably _want_ to do is already achieved by using `\onslide` instead of `\only`